# Best way to minify html in an asp.net mvc 5 application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, minify

I came across several articles about this topic but most of them are outdated. So what is the best way to minify/get rid of the whitespaces when outputing my views html?

Comment: check this http://webmarkupmin.codeplex.com/

Comment: @sarepta does that minify razor code though?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/423.

Answer (score 4):

I built a very trivial minifier called [RazorHtmlMinifier.Mvc5](https://github.com/tompazourek/RazorHtmlMinifier.Mvc5).

It's operating in compile-time when the cshtml Razor files are converted to C# classes, so it won't have any performance overhead at runtime.

The minification is very trivial, basically just replacing multiple spaces with one (because sometimes a space is still significant, e.g. `<span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>` is different to `<span>Hello</span><span>World</span>`).

The source code is very recent and very simple (just [one file with less than 100 lines of code](https://github.com/tompazourek/RazorHtmlMinifier.Mvc5/blob/master/src/RazorHtmlMinifier.Mvc5/MinifyingMvcWebRazorHostFactory.cs)) and installation involves just a NuGet package and changing one line in Web.config file.

And all of this is built for the latest version of ASP.NET MVC 5.

---

Usually, it's recommended to use gzip encoding to minify HTTP responses, but I found out that if you minify the HTML before gzipping, you can still get around 11% smaller responses on average. In my opinion, it's still worth it.

Comment: Thank you for providing this - Meleze.Web wasn't cutting it!

Answer (score 2):

Use WebMarkupMin: ASP.NET 4.X MVC. Install the NuGet package and then use the `MinifyHtmlAttribute` on your action method, controller, or register it in `RegisterGlobalFilters` in `FilterConfig`. You can also try the `CompressContentAttribute`. Here's the wiki: https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/WebMarkupMin:-ASP.NET-4.X-MVC

If you use the CompressContentAttribute you'll see the `Content-Encoding:deflate` header rather than `Content-Encoding:gzip` header if you were using gzip before applying this attribute.

Some test numbers:

No minification or compression:
`Content-Length:21594`

Minification only: `Content-Length:19869`

Minification and compression: `Content-Length:15539`

You'll have to test to see if you're getting speed improvements overall from your changes.

EDIT:

After exhaustive testing locally and on the live site, I've concluded that minifying and compressing HTML with WebMarkupMin in my case slowed the page load time by about 10%. Just compressing (using `CompressContentAttribute`) or just minifying also slowed it down. So I've decided not to compress (using `CompressContentAttribute`) or minify my HTML at all.

Comment: Speeds processing by browser noticeably